# How to enumerate through list with the first "index" reported as 1? (Python 2.4)

Tags: python, python-2.4, enumerator

I need my counter to start at 1. Right now I have

```
for(counter, file) in enumerate(files):
    counter += 1
    //do stuff with file and counter
```

But there must be a better way, in Python v2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `counter += 1`, maybe use `counter + 1` where you've used `counter`.

Alternatively:

```
for counter, file in ((i + 1, f) for i, f in enumerate(files)):
    ...
```

(Python 2.6 and later has some great stuff. Try to upgrade if you can.)

Answer (score 5):

Generators are perfect for this:

```
def altenumerate( it ):
    return ((idx+1, value) for idx, value in enumerate(it))
```

A simplified for older versions of python:

```
def altenumerateOld( it ):
    idx = 1
    for value in it:
        yield (idx, value)
        idx += 1
```

Comment: I guess it's not really a big deal which way I do it, other than for style/simplicity... Would I be better off doing this, or just counter+1?

Comment: You'd be best off upgrading to Python 2.7.

Comment: IMO, it depends how often you need to do it. If you're going to scatter `counter+1` through a heap of loops, then abstract the idea out into a generator expression or function. If it's a one off, anything will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own version of `enumerate()`:

```
def enumerate_1based(iterable):
    for index, item in enumerate(iterable):
        yield index+1, item
```

Alternately, add a `start` argument, to make it work just like later versions of `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> enums = zip(range(1, len(files) + 1), files)
>>> for index, val in enums:
    print index, val
```

Comment: This is a cool answer, but it's worth mentioning that on older versions of python zip and range will be copying lists, and that izip and xrange may be required

Comment: You can swap them over now, but note that `izip` will return a generator.

Answer (score 1):

I did this like this:

```
#Emulate enumerate() with start parameter (introduced in Python 2.6)
for i,v in (i+start,v for i,v in enumerate(seq)):
    //do stuff
```

Basically, this is the same, yet a self-contained construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for counter, item in enumerate(testlist):
    print(counter+1)
    print(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "start" parameter in enumerate method to change starting index.

```
for counter, file in enumerate(files, start=1):
    print(counter, file)
```